# Are there any Monero specific programming language "libraries" available?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, javascript, php, python, programming-languages

I understand that simplewallet has a raw JSON RPC interface available, but are there any specific "helper" libraries available for a relatively modern programming language(PHP, Python, Java, JavaScript, Ruby)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several.

Python: https://github.com/tippero/python-monero

Node js: https://github.com/ShenNoether/monero-nodejs

Php: https://github.com/PsychicCat/monero-php

I think the node and php libraries are for interacting more with simplewallet in particular, but the Python library is for both daemon and wallet I believe.

Comment: no java or client side js libs yet? anyone know what it would take to make / maintain those?

Comment: complete list here: https://getmonero.org/getting-started/merchants

Comment: lethos3, I think that's worth of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For python, you can use [MoneroPy](https://github.com/bigreddmachine/MoneroPy). It is still pre-beta and under development, but has pure python implementations for wallet account creation, TX Extra parsing, integrated address encoding and decoding, transaction ID generation, and other goodies. Speed improvements and Monero Core library wrappers are planned for offloading calculations to same code at used by the core projects (SUPERCOP crypto, etc) rather than using Python, though this is probably a ways off.