# How to use unlock_time?

Tags: transaction-unlock-time

I have just seen that there are some questions here about the unlock_time feature. I never heard about the fact that Monero had something like that enabled, so I was trying to find out more about it, but nothing comes up in the help of either monerod or monero-wallet-cli.

How can I access that feature, and how exactly does it work? I mean, I know the idea that the output would only be used in a transaction after some point in time, or block height, but what are the commands and options, and in what environments is it available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a field in the rpc call to send a transaction, see here: 
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/0edcbf6716cdfd2ea5439a7788cca0041b40a2e2/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server_commands_defs.h#L124

I think the way it works is if you pass that field a number that is less than the start of UNIX time in seconds, then it is interpreted as a block height that the output will be unlocked after, and if you pass it a number greater than the beginning of UNIX time in seconds, then it is interpreted as a UNIX time that the outputs will unlock after.

Comment: If you want some libraries to help out see here: http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/877/are-there-any-monero-specific-programming-language-libraries-available

Comment: That is very interesting information, but could you tell me how exactly can I make such transaction? Perhaps what I am asking is how to use the RPC, assuming there is no simple way to pass the unlock_time as parameter when forming a new transaction.

Comment: You need start the wallet in RPC mode by passing it the --rpc-bind-port and --user-agent flags, then use curl or Python or another way to make RPC calls to the wallet.